# Bypass Geo Redirect for specific directories

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, geolocation

I'm trying to bypass a redirect for the a specific url within my site. Wondering if someone might be able to help.

The code below is the code I use, with original urls replaces by example.com

I'd like to be able to access http://example.com/admin without the redirect occuring.

Is there a way to do this, and is there also a way to do this using your own IP?

```
    function country_geo_redirect()
{

    $country = getenv('HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE');
    if ($country == "US" ) {
        wp_redirect("http://usa.example.com/");
        exit;
    }
    else if ($country == "GB" )
    {
        wp_redirect("http://uk.example.com/");
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'country_geo_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just bypass the redirection code if the server found your IP address.

```
if IP address == <my ip address> then
 ' do nothing here
else
  country_georedirect()
end if
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this generally on a global level rather than just IP?

Comment: You can use a special parameters such as key=password to bypass geolocation feature. In this case, you can visit the admin pages as long as you put the password in the URL parameters.